# Android 4.x Webview Hash tags

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So i've embeded a HTML jQuery element within an Android application, for some bizzare reason on Android 4.x i always get a page not found.

it's a very simple structure:

```
file.html#hash
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that android 4.x does not like hashed url's

```
file.html#hash
```

Did not work but `file.html` works fine, after some research the android 4.x application was trying to find the a file named `file.html#hash` but no such file existed in our directory.

To fix this problem I had to re-write the javascript to allow a direct link to the page of `file.html` and then hash on the next event.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.